# Loop cut + Wheel does not work (does not add edges)

Tags: tools

I cannot find what I am doing wrong during loop cutting: I want to add some edges, but the wheel enlarges the view area instead of adding ribs.

Sometimes it works as it should - I select the Loop Cut tool, then go to a specific edge and start rotate the wheel and it adds more edges - I cannot find why it is not constant behavior.

Comment: Without seeing your mesh I can only guess, but _Loop Cut_ only works correct on quads. This is a guess for it not working at all. For the missing feature to increase the edges: well, zooming with the mouse wheel is usually a standard function when you're not actively using a tool. Are you sure you haven't finished the _Loop Cut_ and tried to add edges after making a cut? If so, then I can only suspect it's a bug. Which Blender version are you using?

Comment: i added an answer, could you please check in your version that I am right?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you open up tool settings:

[image]

You will see the **Number of cuts** slider, so that you can change the amount of cuts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the loop cut was chosen from the toolbar, the mouse wheel won't add edges (will zoom instead).

To make wheel function available you should use a shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Ah okay, I never use the tool through the menu, I always use the shortcut so I didn't know it makes a difference. Especially since you wrote in the question "Sometimes it works as it should - I select the Loop Cut tool [...] I cannot find why it is not constant behavior" which gave me the impression that you use the tool from the menu and sometimes it works, sometimes not... which makes it sound like a bug. But your answer implies it never works from the menu, only with the shortcut - which makes quite a difference to question.

Comment: marked as duplicate. I never knew there is a diff between a tool and a shortcut. Sounds crazy